# And OR in same column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a simple table in SQL server 2008.

```
SELECT TOP lastupdated, remarks   FROM table
```

I want to select the following criteria.

if remarks is `'Others'` and `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LastUpdated, GETDATE() ) > 15` 
then select these rows

Additionally, I want to select following in the same query 
if remarks is not 'Others'
then select these rows without waiting for 15 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep first to condition in braces and then add OR condition like below:

```
SELECT TOP lastupdated , remarks   FROM table
WHERE (remarks = 'Others' AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LastUpdated, GETDATE()) > 15)
OR remarks <> 'Others'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:

```
select LastUpdated, Remarks
from table
where (remarks = 'Others' and datediff(min, LastUpdated, GETDATE()) > 15)
      or remarks != 'Others'
```

You can adjust the `TOP x`, according to your needs, since you didn't put it in your question so I didn't know how many rows you needed to select.

Answer (score 4):

A `case` expression should help you here:

```
SELECT TOP lastupdated, remarks
FROM   mytable
WHERE  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LastUpdated, GETDATE() ) > CASE remarks WHEN 'Others' THEN 15 ELSE -1 END
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just nest your WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT  lastupdated , remarks
FROM    table
WHERE   remarks != 'Others'
        OR
        (
            remarks = 'Others'
            AND
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LastUpdated, GETDATE() ) > 15
        )
```